# Django CMS how to use different urls for 2 instances of the same apphook

Tags: django, django-urls, django-cms

Following the tutorial of the djangocms documentation, I've created an apphook to allow users to ask for registration to a list of newsletters. Clicking on the page menu goes to the `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')` of the hooked application. It works fine.

I would like to create a second page for the newsletters administrator that will use another instance of the same application but using the `url(r'^manage/$', views.manage, name='manage')` when the page is selected. Is it possible? I don't find how to configure that.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lack of a better way, I have usually created another App Hook and pointed it to another view - that way you can have every major part of the app catered for. If it's just two different pages, this may be the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, how do you define the view on which you want to point (if this one is not the root)?

Answer (score 0):

In a page's advanced settings is the `application instance name` which is there to enable the same apphook to be used on multiple pages. Setting that would get you two instances of the same apphook.

Alternatively, and perhaps more appropriately, you could split your URLs into a separate file for management. Then you could have a `NewsletterManagementAppHook` which points to that new set of URLs, separate from the frontend URLs for users. That way you can setup another apphook on another page.